# Usinf System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to write to a log file when a file is created

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to monitor a directory for the creation of files. If a file is created,  I want to write a single line out to a logfile and carry on monitoring the folder. I'm using this code below but I get a double entry in the log file.

If I put breaks into the `$action` I can see that it runs through that twice before waiting for the next event, which is why it writes two line to the log file.

What have I got wrong?

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\test-folder"
$watcher.Filter = "*FINAL*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true 
$watcher.InternalBufferSize = 16384 

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER A EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-Content "C:\test-folder\created.log" -value $logline
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED + SET CHECK FREQUENCY  
$created = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
#    $changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
#    $deleted = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
#    $renamed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

log file looks like this...

```
05/03/2016 11:25:16, Created, C:\test-folder\test1-FINAL-.txt
05/03/2016 11:25:16, Created, C:\test-folder\test1-FINAL-.txt
05/03/2016 11:26:10, Created, C:\test-folder\test2-FINAL-.txt
05/03/2016 11:26:10, Created, C:\test-folder\test2-FINAL-.txt
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Are you certain that you didn't register the watcher twice?

Comment: erm, don't know - if i close the ps shell and re-open that should clear any watchers?  - and if I run it with "write and read host" as breaks in the $action { i can see it loop thru twice. ...

Answer (score 2):

You should read this topic [LastWrite FileSystemWatcher Powershell: notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791979/lastwrite-filesystemwatcher-powershell-notification)

> You may notice in certain situations that a single creation event generates multiple Created events that are handled by your component. For example, if you use a FileSystemWatcher component to monitor the creation of new files in a directory, and then test it by using Notepad to create a file, you may see two Created events generated even though only a single file was created. This is because Notepad performs multiple file system actions during the writing process. Notepad writes to the disk in batches that create the content of the file and then the file attributes. Other applications may perform in the same manner. Because FileSystemWatcher monitors the operating system activities, all events that these applications fire will be picked up.

Comment: oh - ok (i'm using Notepad++ to create the test file) i just tried i with just a file copy and that only created one line in the log.

 tried it with winword (which is what will be creating the files in the live environment) and I got 3 events - two for the file name and one for the ~$<filename> that word creates. So, I'll need to put a filter in to not log #$ files. But that doesn't solve my double entry issue.

I could live with the double entry in the log file - but I'm using it to send to #slack  too & I don't really want multiple messages.

Is there a better way than FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: Another way is just to check the folder yourself. Store the current files in a variable and use compare-object to check if there are new files. If there are new files then just do what you want in the if statement.

Comment: yes - I had thought of that but didn't really know where to start :), but there are many subfolders with many hundreds of files being added (although not that many of the file type I'm looking for) - i just assumed that the overhead would be higher than FSW...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the timestamp to set a global variable that I compare against to check if its a duplicate.

not the best solution as potentially anything created a second apart will still result in a double entry, but it works in our situation.

thanks for everyone's input.