# How to raise an event when a process is done in Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell

I would like to use Powershell to Start an application with some options of Start-Process as the code and then close the application after the process is done. The process is to measure some signals.
At first, this process is done by the C# code but I think this function can be converted to Powershell. However I dont' know how to do that, especially, with the Process.Exited and Process.EnableRaisingEvents.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

```
public void Execute_process(string console_path, string arg1)
        {
            try
            {
                //プロセス作成
                p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = console_path + "\\" + "IQfactRun_Console.exe";
                //p.StartInfo.Verb = "RunAs";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -run " + ini["IQFACT", "flow_folder"] + "\\" + arg1;
                Debug.WriteLine("arg:" + " -run " + ini["IQFACT", "flow_folder"] + "\\" + arg1);
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = ini["IQFACT", "Console_file"];
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                p.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_exited);
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                //プロセス実行状態に設定
                run_status = true;

                //外部プロセス起動
                p.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("例外発生:" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Register-ObjectEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16219054/16297051)?

Comment: @GraphWalk could you detail how to use that function? Thank you